# Showing that$(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\cdot[(\vec{b}+\vec{c})\times(\vec{c}+\vec{a})]=2\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

> $$(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\cdot[(\vec{b}+\vec{c})\times(\vec{c}+\vec{a})]=2\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})$$

Is there an option to prove it using the properties of dot and cross product? or do I need to take a general vectors to show it? can I use vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: This doesn't make sense: The l.h.s. is a scalar but the r.h.s. is a vector. Probably the r.h.s. should be $2 {\bf a} \cdot ({\bf b} \times {\bf c})$.

Comment: @Travis yes, sorry, fixed

Comment: Actually, this appears to be a duplicate.

Comment: The comment is correct. Firstly, $$x\cdot(y\times z)=(x\times y)\cdot z$$ which is a [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product). It is tri-linear, or you can also say it's associative. So when you expand your first triple product, you get a sum of 8 triple products. If two out of $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the same, the triple product is zero. That happens for 6 of them, the two remaining are $a\cdot(b\times c)$ and $b\cdot(c\times a)$, which are the same.